# Fill the region with Black color

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project for my subject, wherein I made a website for a service.
Unfortunately I am in  a condition which is not going properly
The screenshot of the page is: [image]

I want to fill the entire red box region with black background color.

Html code: `

```
<body background="black">
<div id=pagehead>
    <div class=imagehead>
        <img class=imageheadsrc src="./pics/back.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class=texthead>
        <p class=textheadsrc>CaRental.com</p>
    </div>
 </div><br>
 <br><br>

<button id="myBtn">Login</button>

  <button id="myBtn">Register</button>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

   <!-- Modal content -->
   <div class="modal-content">
   <span class="close">x</span>
   <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
   </div>
   <script>
   // Get the modal
     var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

      // Get the button that opens the modal
     var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

      // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
      btn.onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "block";
     }

     // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
     span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }

      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
     </script>

    </div>
     </body>
   </html>`
```

CSS CODE:

```
           *html{
        background-color:black;
           }
           body{
        background-color:black;
         }


     #pagehead
     {
          width:100%;
            height: 700px;
      }
      .imagehead
         {
                width:100%;
               height:100%;
          background-position: absolute;
          background-size: cover;
       }     
        .imageheadsrc
          {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-size: cover;
            z-index: 0;
       }
        .texthead
       {
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-top:0%;
        z-index: -1;
       }
        .textheadsrc{
        position: relative;
        font-size: 3em;
          font-weight: bold;
       margin:10px 12px auto 10px;
        color:black;
          text-align:center;
      font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
          }


                   button {
      background-color: white;
         color: black;
        border: 2px solid #4CAF50; /* Green */
        padding: 15px 50px;
        position:center;
         text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
         display: inline-block;
          font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
     }

      button:hover {
      background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
          color: white;
       text-decoration: none;
     }


     .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
         top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
         background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
          }

      /* Modal Content/Box */
      .modal-content {
       background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
         width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
        }

       /* The Close Button */
     .close {
         color: #aaa;
         float: right;
         font-size: 28px;
         font-weight: bold;
         }



    .close:hover,
     .close:focus {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
       cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Please guide me to this as I am new to html and css.

Comment: .texthead
       {
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-top:0%;
        z-index: -1; background:#000;color:#fff
       }

Answer (score 0):

You could add `style="background-color:black;"` to the element, to give it a black background.

I also noticed that you were using `background="black"` in the `body` tag. That is deprecated, you should use the `style="background-color:black;"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the rule in your CSS:

```
.texthead {
     background-color: black;
     /* The rest of your CSS goes here...*/
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get a black color only on the text line with 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Style "texthead" in your CSS with 
    background-color:black;

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mistakes:
 1. DO NOT use INLINE css. Write css properties in external file.
 2. Close your "" f.ex class="className".
 3. Use properly break tag and do not use it to put the div on the next line - it is totally wrong.
 4. Use HEX values to set colors for different elements (like #000 / #000000 - Black color).
 5. When using IMG tag add width="", height="" of the image for faster rendering, title="" and alt="" tag for SEO purposes.
 6. Do not use ID's because they are unique, rely more on classes and when you really need add ID to the element.
 7. Fix your -prefix- attribute, add for chrome, moz, ie not only -webkit- for safari.
 8. Do not use % based values for margin's, use pixel or em's instead.

Umhh and a lot more mistakes.. but for now focus on these problems that you have and if you fix them you will be able to change your background-color: #000000; to black :).

Hope that you can fix this easy issues.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for pointing out, I hope to learn more. However adding background-color:#000000; doesnt color the background everything remains the same.